# Calculating wheel loads on a motorcycle / car / bike

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I have found many pictures on how to look at the forces here, for example [THIS](https://www.google.at/search?q=achslast%20fahrrad%20physik&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjI5LCsj8foAhWKKuwKHcK9C9EQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=achslast%20fahrrad%20physik&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CDB1ibDWDDDWgAcAB4AYABrgGIAeUEkgEDNS4xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWc&sclient=img&ei=dXqEXojWAYrVsAfC-66IDQ&bih=885&biw=1901#imgrc=QTmR16ugf5UF2M). It bothers me that this doesn't seem to be correct. Since the wheels turn (and the slipping of the tyre is about 20% at maximum friction force) - shouldn't only the frame be looked at - and so forces on the wheel axis? Some "dynamic of motor vehicle" books tell me so.

Has anyone got experience in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Calculation the Car Wheels Load**

[image]

- $F_G=m\,g$ car weight

  - $F_V$ wheel front load
  - $F_H$ wheel rear load
  - $a_A$ car acceleration
  - $a_D$  car deceleration

take the sum of the torques about point V you get:

$$\sum \tau_V=F_H\,l-F_G\,l_V-m\,a_A\,h_s+m\,a_D\,h_s=0\tag 1$$

or about point H

$$\sum \tau_H=F_V\,l-F_G\,l_H+m\,a_A\,h_s-m\,a_D\,h_s=0\tag 2$$

from equation (1) you get for the rear wheel  load:

$$F_H=\frac{F_G\,l_V}{l}+\frac{m\,a_A\,h_s}{l}-\frac{m\,a_D\,h_s}{l}$$

and from equation (2) you get for the front wheel  load:
$$F_V=\frac{F_G\,l_H}{l}-\frac{m\,a_A\,h_s}{l}+\frac{m\,a_D\,h_s}{l}$$

thus:

if you brake  your car ($a_A=0\,,a_D >0$) you get at the front wheel  greater wheel load then at the rear wheel, because $l_H >l_V$

Comment: Hi Thanks! I have seen people also mark friction forces between the ground and the wheels like in https://www.google.at/search?q=fahrrad+kr%C3%A4fte&sxsrf=ALeKk00koDblRbn0wKMTpvxVCwW09Zhvjw:1585763281747&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNxOzI5MfoAhUPTcAKHbObAKcQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1655&bih=806#imgrc=TQ-lSVsqbbvf1M. What is correct then? or, Is that correct? Telling from your post it isnt, because it should then be considered as a force of inertia (D'alembert)

Comment: I don’t think that friction affected the wheel load, but air drag can affect the wheels load , if the velocity of the car is high.

Comment: if friction leads to a bigger deceleration then it surely does or am I wrong?

Comment: the friction force is between  the wheel and the road. if you take the sum of the torques at point V or point H there is no frictions torques an those points, thus the frictions forces  don't affects the wheels load.

Comment: but what if friction forces lead to a deceleration of the car? It must change.

Comment: So the value of the deceleration is changed

Comment: which then leads to different wheel loads.